# How to assign capabilities to user NOT to User Role

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities

Is there any way to assign custom capabilities to user, I'm NOT talking about User Role.

I'm running a multi author blog where I assigned user role of "Author" to all of my authors. But I need a plugin or function.php snippet that remove a capability(not the role) from USER-ID

#### NOTE -

I dont want to assign/revoke capabilities to role ( administrator/author etc) I want to assign/revoke them to specific user using that users ID.

#### UPDATE - 08/01/2012

I have blog with suppose 50 authors, A author have capabilities to do post, comment, edit, update, send emails, share etc. but when a user misuses one of this feature I want to revoke that capability/capabilities from that user.

But If I decide to using roles I'd have to create so many user roles with different capabilities such as

- cannot send
- cannot send & comment
- cannot send & comment & post
  etc.

Is there a way to revoke a capability from user(not the USER-ROLE)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I grant capabilities directly to users (not roles) in wp-admin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17726/how-can-i-grant-capabilities-directly-to-users-not-roles-in-wp-admin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I've figured out a way to do it using [`WP_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) Class.

Snippet to add/remove capability to/from specific user -

```
//to remove capability from user
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->remove_cap( 'can_email');

//to add capability to user
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->add_cap( 'can_email');
```

There is special function in [capabilities.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L808) in the `wp_user` class to assign/revoke capability to/from user.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new role with required capabilities and then assign the user to it.

you can use  [add_role()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) and pass the capabilities needed.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I was looking to add/remove a capability from user not from role..
However I've figured out a way to do it. See answer.

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to assign capabilities to already existing roles or (already created custom roled) then there is  global variables called $wp_roles

```
//suppose you have a custom role called 'architect' and you want to add a capability called `can access architect zone`
global $wp_roles;
$wp_roles->add_cap( 'architect', 'can_access_architect_zone' );
//add to default roles
$wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'monitor_architect' );
```

Comment: thanks, but using wp_user I can assign/revoke a capability to user.. added my answer for others.