# When using a user role editor how to find out any plugins' or themes' role?

Tags: user-roles

Suppose I'm using a Theme which has a custom panel in the admin area, or I'm using a Plugin, has similar Admin menu button. But all such button are only visible to Administrator. When I'm loggin in from an editor account they are gone.

But I need them badly. I want an Editor can have access to those panels, and I want to let them the privilege.

In that case I'll need to know the theme's or plugin's specific ROLE's or CAPABILITIES' name and then I'll need to assign 'em to a certain user. But here comes the million dollar question:

- HOW COME I FIND OUT A THEME'S OR PLUGIN'S SPECIFIC CAPABILITIES?

  ```
  //suppose you have a custom role called 'architect' and you want to add a capability called `can access architect zone`
  global $wp_roles;
  $wp_roles->add_cap( 'architect', 'can_access_architect_zone' );
  ```

code cited from:[this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57977/how-to-assign-capabilities-to-user-not-to-user-role)

How can I assume that the plugin or theme uses the 'can_access_architect_zone' as its capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functions like [add_submenu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) ask for a capability when they are called, as in de code below:

```
add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

`$capability` contains the [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) required for this menu to be displayed to the user.

When you want to know wich Roles and Capabilities are used in a theme or plugin, you could take a look in de code and search for these kind of functions.

Also, if you downloaded a theme or plugin, you could give it a try to search for this information on the developers website.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder how can I get the `$parent_slug`, `$menu_slug` from such a theme/plugin? I can hide the total menu by deleting or commenting out code like: `add_action('init', 'slideshow_register');`. But that's not the proper solution. When I'm clicking on the specific menu, it generates: `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=slideshow`, I tried with the assumed slug "slideshow" and with "slideshow_register", but can't get the desired result. And `$parent_slug`, `$menu_slug` are REQUIRED.

Comment: You're looking for capabilities of a registered post_type. In this case, you probably should take a look into the function `slideshow_register` and search in the _arguments_ of the function `register_post_type`. In these _arguments_, search for the argument `capabilities` (more info about this [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)). There you'll have to find the capabilities you are looking for.